# Plug in for Responsive Image Maps

Tags: image, product-images

We are using Community Edition 1.9.2.4

We are looking for a plug in or add on, to create image maps that have multiple links attached.

Something similar to www.decori.co.uk/designs/

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no such extension available for magento right now, but you can make use of [jQuery RWD Image Maps](https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps)

It has working demo here:

http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html#blossom

Although I have not used it but it seems that it would be easy to integrate as there are only 2 js files and a well documented usage instructions set.